# R: calculate number of occurrences which have started but not ended - count if within a datetime range

Tags: r, date, datetime, dplyr, tidyverse

I've got a dataset with the following shape

```
ID     Start Time             End Time
1   01/01/2017 00:15:00  01/01/2017 07:15:00
2   01/01/2017 04:45:00  01/01/2017 06:15:00
3   01/01/2017 10:20:00  01/01/2017 20:15:00
4   01/01/2017 02:15:00  01/01/2017 00:15:00
5   02/01/2017 15:15:00  03/01/2017 00:30:00
6   03/01/2017 07:00:00  04/01/2017 09:15:00
```

I would like to count every 15 min for an entire year how many items have started but not finished, so count the number of times with a start time greater or equal than the time I'm looking at and an end time less or equal than the time I'm looking at.

I'm looking for an approach using tidyverse/dplyr if possible.

Any help or guidance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: So what have you tried so far? You can find plenty of posts with related problem statements here on SO that should get you started. I didn't downvote your question but in order to avoid further negative response, I recommend spending time towards working out a solution yourself; then if you get stuck, come back here and ask a specific question. Otherwise this sounds too much like a ["gimme teh codez" request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108551/what-site-to-use-if-you-have-a-gimme-teh-codez-question).

Comment: Thanks @MauritsEvers, and sorry for the generic question. The thing is that I cannot get my head around on how to do this using a dplyr approach. I think I could manage to do it using sqldf, but I'm looking for a faster dplyr approach, as I'm dealing with millions of rows for over several years.

Comment: And I could do a for loop and go through the dataset filtering and counting the rows matching the criteria, but I'm trying to avoid loops.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to count the number of simultaneously active events.

One possibility to tackle this question is the `coverage()` function from Bioconductor's `IRange` package. Another one is to *aggregate in a non-equi join* which is available with the `data.table` package.

#### Non-equi join

```
# create sequence of datetimes (limited to 4 days for demonstration)
seq15 <- seq(lubridate::as_datetime("2017-01-01"), 
          lubridate::as_datetime("2017-01-05"), by = "15 mins")
# aggregate within a non-equi join
library(data.table)
result <- periods[.(time = seq15), on = .(Start.Time <= time, End.Time > time), 
        .(time, count = sum(!is.na(ID))), by = .EACHI][, .(time, count)]
result
```

> ```
>                     time count
>   1: 2017-01-01 00:00:00     0
>   2: 2017-01-01 00:15:00     1
>   3: 2017-01-01 00:30:00     1
>   4: 2017-01-01 00:45:00     1
>   5: 2017-01-01 01:00:00     1
>  ---                          
> 381: 2017-01-04 23:00:00     0
> 382: 2017-01-04 23:15:00     0
> 383: 2017-01-04 23:30:00     0
> 384: 2017-01-04 23:45:00     0
> 385: 2017-01-05 00:00:00     0
> ```

The result can be visualized graphically:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(result) + aes(time, count) + geom_step()
```

[image]

#### Data

```
periods <- readr::read_table(
  "ID     Start.Time             End.Time
1   01/01/2017 00:15:00  01/01/2017 07:15:00
2   01/01/2017 04:45:00  01/01/2017 06:15:00
3   01/01/2017 10:20:00  01/01/2017 20:15:00
4   01/01/2017 02:15:00  01/01/2017 00:15:00
5   02/01/2017 15:15:00  03/01/2017 00:30:00
6   03/01/2017 07:00:00  04/01/2017 09:15:00"
)

# convert date strings to class Date
library(data.table)
cols <- names(periods)[names(periods) %like% "Time$"]
setDT(periods)[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, lubridate::dmy_hms), .SDcols = cols]
periods
```

> ```
>    ID          Start.Time            End.Time
> 1:  1 2017-01-01 00:15:00 2017-01-01 07:15:00
> 2:  2 2017-01-01 04:45:00 2017-01-01 06:15:00
> 3:  3 2017-01-01 10:20:00 2017-01-01 20:15:00
> 4:  4 2017-01-01 02:15:00 2017-01-01 00:15:00
> 5:  5 2017-01-02 15:15:00 2017-01-03 00:30:00
> 6:  6 2017-01-03 07:00:00 2017-01-04 09:15:00
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much! If I wanted to do the counts and aggregation by several categories (different columns) , how would you make it work using data.table?

Comment: @Eloy, Thank you for asking but I am not sure if I understand your request. Do you mean additional start/end time columns or value columns? What is the expected result? May I respectfully suggest that you post a new question, please.